# for what $\theta \in [0, 2\pi[$ we have $\cos\theta \leq a\sin\theta +b$ where $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

#### Problem

> for what $\theta \in [0, 2\pi[$ we have $\cos\theta \leq a\sin\theta +b$, $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$

My attempt :
All I can say is that when $\vert b \vert$ is large enough, either every or no $\theta \in [0, 2\pi[$ works. But I can't find a way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Problem is complicated because you have $~2^4 = 16~$ separate cases to deal with, since each of $~a,b,\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)~$ could be negative or non-negative.  Assuming that all four values are non-negative, then you have that $$[ ~cos(\theta) - b ~]^2 \leq a^2 [~1 - cos^2(\theta) ~].$$  This results in a quadratic equation in the variable $~\cos(\theta),~$ so you will be able to identify the range of satisfying (non-negative) values of $~\cos(\theta),~$ in terms of the non-negative constants $~a,b.~$  This is routine.

Comment: Re last comment, I suggest that you forgo any attempt at elegance, and plow through the 16 cases, one at a time.  Then, at the end, when you are getting ready to summarize your results, you may (or may not) see shortcuts that will allow you combine some of the cases, as you report them.  In my opinion, it is irrelevant whether elegant shortcuts to the original problem exist.  If you haven't been taught any such shortcuts in your class, then the intent of the problem composer must be the inelegant approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequality can be written as

$ a \sin \theta - \cos \theta \ge -b \tag{1}$

By combining the two sinusoid above, it can re-written as

$ \sqrt{a^2 + 1} \cos( \theta - \theta_1 ) \ge - b \tag{2} $

where

$ \theta_1 = \text{Atan2}( -1, a ) \tag{3} $

i.e. $\theta_1$ is the angle that satisfies $\cos \theta_1 = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}} $ and $\sin \theta_1 = \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}} $

From $(2)$, we have

$ \cos(\theta - \theta_1) \ge - \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \tag{4} $

Let

$ \phi = \cos^{-1} \left( - \dfrac{ b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \right) \tag{5} $

Then this gives the range for $\theta$ as follows

$ \theta_1 - \phi \le \theta \le \theta_1 + \phi \tag{6} $

**Special Cases:**

We know that for any angle $\psi$,

$ -1 \le \cos \psi \le 1 \tag{7} $

Therefore, looking at $(4)$, we conclude that

1. If $ - \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1} } \le -1 $ then the range for $\theta$ is $[0, 2\pi) $
2. If $ - \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1} } \gt 1 $ then the range for $\theta$ is the empty set $\{ \}$, i.e. the inequality in $(1)$ has no solutions.